# What authentication does applications that tweet on our behalf use?

Tags: java, twitter, oauth

I created a Twitter App from my twitter account. It gave me four things

```
Consumer Key
Consumer Key Secret
Access Token
Access Token Secret
```

For a while I am using these 4 things to tweet,retweet from the application that I am writing. It is cool that I can access the Twitter API
using these 4 keys, which is also called `OAuth`. But these keys are secret to me .

What authentication does applications, that tweet,schedules and may be other stuff use ? I beleive they cannot use `OAuth` for the reason it will
need the 4 keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The consumer key and consumer secret identify *your application*. These credentials are necessary for any requests you are performing on the Twitter API.

The access token and access token secret identify *your Twitter account*. This couple is given to you for convenience so you can get started immediately with the Twitter API and start signing OAuth requests and perform actions on your personal account.

However, if you are creating a Twitter application that other people can use, you will want them to sign in using their own Twitter account and obtain an access token for them. This way, your application will be able to interact with their account.

Read more about [Implementing Sign in with Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter) and [Troubleshooting OAuth 1.0A](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/204).